# Ubuntu 20.04 Terminal Using the Screen Command

Tags: server, screen, amazon-ec2

I've been using the "screen" linux command on an AWS EC2 instance to keep code running 24/7. Recently I tried the command in my ubuntu terminal and found that if I make a screen, run a program, and close the screen properly, the code will continue running even if I turn off WiFi, turn off my computer, etc. I was very surprised by this because I thought the code ran locally in a terminal so would stop running if I did something like this.

Does anyone know how this works? I figure it must be running on ubuntu's servers, but I find that surprising that they wouldn't charge me for that, while AWS does charge.

Comment: Please describe further where you are running the code? do you open a terminal and just run the screen command? without running `ssh `?  Could you please confirm that the username and PC name just before the blinker in the terminal matches your local computer? It is not possible that you turn off a computer and the computer keeps working. So, I believe you are running the command on a remote computer and somehow you are not aware of it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. You're right, I tried shutting down again and it cut off the screen. It must be running locally and I thought for some reason I had shut down. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I posted the answer with more details in the answer section; feel free to mark it as an answer. @d22fish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of the screen is to prevent losing access to a session and to prevent code from stopping if the terminal window gets closed/ssh connection drops.

In your case, If the code is running after a reconnect; you are definitely connected to a remote computer. By any shutdown/reboot, all the programs including `screen` will be stopped, and you have to re-run after startup.

`tmux` is a more advanced version of `screen` with a lot more features. I recommend checking out its features and switching if the features suit your type of work.

As of now `tmux` might be not pre-installed on your distribution; the installation is as easy as:

```
sudo apt install tmux
```

or

```
yum install tmux
```